# Compile and Export C++ Xcode Project?

Tags: c++, xcode

from this question you can see I am an extremely new coder. I was just wondering how can I compile and export a C++ console app on Xcode. By this I mean make it a runnable console app for my mac.

Comment: "Export" meaning what? There are template projects you can create which produce a command-line executable in C++ if that's what you're asking.

Comment: For a simple executable project the binary will typically be in the DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug or DerivedData/Build/Products/Release directories.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode has a template for command line applications (File->New->Project->MacOS->Command Line Tool). Therein, you add your `.c` or `.cpp` files and build. In the Project's navigator (left pane), you'll find a folder "Products", listing your compiled command line program. When you right-click on it, you can "show in finder"; probably the easiest way to find out where the executable is built. Open a terminal, `cd` to that directory, and then you can call it, e.g. with `./myProgram`.